# SwiftUI - detect change in Textfield

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I want when user edit information in textfield it will listen for change -> Save button will change from Gray to Blue and enable. If the user has not edited the information, the save button will disable.

I want when user edit information in textfield it will listen for change -> Save button will change from Gray to Blue. If the user has not edited the information, the save button will disable

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68055969/12299030?

Comment: but I don't know how can implement it for Save button

Comment: Use onChange for the question u asked.

Comment: can you edit it on my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple example that maybe of use to you, using some of the comments advice. There are 3 main elements, the condition, the disabling and the color.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var passwordRepeat = ""
    
    // here the condition you want
    var isConfirmed: Bool { 
        if !password.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty &&
            !passwordRepeat.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty &&
            (password == passwordRepeat) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SecureField("password", text: $password)
            SecureField("password confirm", text: $passwordRepeat)
            Button(action: { } ) {
                Text("SAVE").accentColor(.white)
            }
            .disabled(!isConfirmed) // <-- here to enable/disable the button
            .padding(20)
            .background(isConfirmed ? Color.green : Color.gray) // <-- here to change color of the button
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }.frame(width: 333)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

here is an approach to make the condition work with when your Textfield already has content in it:

```
// your ProfileEditorRow equivalent
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
    let refUserName: String // <-- reference user name
    
    init(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
        self.profileViewModel = profileViewModel
        self.refUserName = profileViewModel.user.name // <-- here keep the initial user name
    }
    
    var isCondition: Bool {
        return (refUserName == profileViewModel.name) // <-- here test for change
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("test",text: $profileViewModel.user.name)
            Button(action: { print("----> SAVE") } ) {
                Text("SAVE").accentColor(.white)
            }
            .disabled(isCondition) // <-- here to enable/disable the button
            .padding(20)
            .background(isCondition ? Color.gray : Color.green) // <-- here to change color of the button
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }.frame(width: 333)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
```

EDIT2: sample with multiple elements in condition

You probably have a `User` struct with name, birthday etc... using this:

```
struct User {
    var name
    var birthday
    var gender
    // ....
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
    let refUser: User // <-- reference user
    
    init(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
        self.profileViewModel = profileViewModel
        self.refUser = profileViewModel.user // <-- here keep the initial user values
    }
    
    var isCondition: Bool {
        return (refUser.name == profileViewModel.user.name) &&
        (refUser.birthday == profileViewModel.user.birthday)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("name",text: $profileViewModel.user.name)
            TextField("birthday",text: $profileViewModel.user.birthday)
            Button(action: { print("----> SAVE") } ) {
                Text("SAVE").accentColor(.white)
            }
            .disabled(isCondition) // <-- here to enable/disable the button
            .padding(20)
            .background(isCondition ? Color.gray : Color.green) // <-- here to change color of the button
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }.frame(width: 333)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to get the condition when my Textfield already has content in it

Comment: @David if your textfields has already content then check the variable which is connected to the textfield.

Comment: updated my answer with a working approach when the Textfield already has content in it.

Comment: updated my answer. If this answer helps, please mark it as such.